# No wireless on Zorin

Tags: wifi, zorin

I have installed Zorin OS beside my XP but cannot find a wireless connection. While I can connect using the wired interface, the connection is dropped whenever I go into Software Updates. It will only come back after I reboot.

My machine has a Broadcom Wireless 1370 WLAN-Mini-PCI Card and Zorin has installed the alternate driver: Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA Wireless Driver.

I am a new user of Linux with no experience, what should I do from here?

Comment: Welcome to U&L. This is not a forum, it is a Queston and Answer site. We value *crisp* questions, that makes it easier to read and answer and makes it more likely that someone else recognises their problem in the question.